# How to check the month and a year of a procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle

So I'm trying to create a procedure in Oracle SQL developer. The procedure receives a year and a month as a number, and then we check the attribute "Date" (which its type is DATE) from a table, if the month and the year are equal to the ones the procedure receives, then we print that table. But I'm getting a lot of errors, and is not working.

```
create or replace procedure PR_SALE( month number, year number ) is
cursor c is
select v.OID_V, v.DATE, v.SHIPPING_COSTS
from ( SALES v inner join CLIENT c on ( v.OID_CL = c.OID_CL ) )
where MONTH(v.DATE) = month
and YEAR(v.DATE) = year
order by v.DATE;
fila c%rowtype;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Sales list in  ' || month || ' from '|| year );
dbms_output.put_line(' ');
for fila in c loop
dbms_output.put_line(
rpad( fila.DATE, 20 ) ||
rpad( fila.SHIPPING COSTS, 20 ) ||
rpad( fila.OID_V, 20 )
);
end loop;
end ;
```

I'm getting the following errors.

```
Error(208,9): PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'C' is incomplete or malformed
Error(209,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(214,7): PL/SQL: Item ignored
Error(219,2): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(220,8): PLS-00364: loop index variable 'FILA' use is invalid
```

Comment: Did you look up the syntax in the docs? And no, this is not MySQL!

Comment: Pay attention to ORA-00942; even if you write that code correctly, you'll have to have access to the table. Maybe you misspelled it, or it isn't in your schema, or ... who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just do it like this:

```
create or replace procedure PR_SALE( p_month number, p_year number ) is
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Sales list in  ' || p_month || ' from '|| p_year);
    dbms_output.put_line(' ');
    for fila in (select  v.OID_V, v.DATE, v.SHIPPING_COSTS
        from ( SALES v inner join CLIENT c on ( v.OID_CL = c.OID_CL ) )
        where to_number(to_char(v.DATE, 'MM')) = p_month 
        and to_number(to_char(v.DATE,'YYYY')) = p_year 
        order by v.DATE) 
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(
        rpad( fila.DATE, 20 ) ||
        rpad( fila.SHIPPING COSTS, 20 ) ||
        rpad( fila.OID_V, 20 )
        );
    end loop;
end;
/
```

"month" and "year" are keywords, which is why I prefixed them with p_. It might work anyway, but it's not generally good practice to use keywords as variable names.